# What do you say when you wish someone to do well the next time they run?

Tags: idioms, phrase-requests

A friend of mine was leaving to start running as an exercise and I said "Have a good run!". Then I found out it is [an idiom](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/have+a+good+run) with a different meaning. What is the right thing to say in that case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would think that in the context of someone actually running, there is no danger of confusion. "Have a good run" is perfectly appropriate for wishing someone do well while running.

I guess if confusion was a real concern, you could say "run well!"